# inhabilitar una vista en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Hola que tal tengo una pregunta estoy trabajando en un proyecto en laravel 8 y mi caso es que mi sitio  solamente va a tener un único administrador, entonces utilizando el register lo doy de alta para que pueda exceder después con el login.
Mi duda es: Cómo le haría una vez con el usuario creado deshabilitar únicamente esa vista la de register para que nadie más se pueda crearse una cuenta?
Y más aún estando ya en producción
Ojalá haya Sido algo claro
O espero que alguien tenga una idea de cómo abordar de la mejor manera el probablema, soy nuevo en laravel

Comment: Agrega un nuevo atributo para cada usuario que sea el rol ej: (normal, admin), luego asigna un middleware a las rutas validando por el respectivo rol según el contexto de la ruta.
[Documentación de lo que es y hace un middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware)

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mi recomendación seria que si no quieres que nadie se registro, es que tu desde el inicio al correr las migraciones de tu base, tambien envies los seed o llenes la base con el usuario y no crees la pagina del registro.

[Seeder - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding)

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, en estos casos es mejor evitar responderlas